# how to get rid of duplicate gridview in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to populate a gridview using a SQL dataadapter in a DOTNETNUKE module. My problem is that i get a "duplicate" table when i do this. Any insights for me?

This is my code behind

```
        SqlCommand command          = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter      = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds                  = new DataSet();           
        SqlConnection connection    = new SqlConnection(connString);

        connection.Open();
        command.Connection  = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "PopulateGridView";
        adapter             = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connection.Close();

        gvStatusUpdate.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gvStatusUpdate.DataBind();
```

This is My frond end code for the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStatusUpdate" runat="server">
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ReportedDate" DataField="ReportedDate"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CurrentStatus" DataField="CurrentStatus"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ResolvedDate" DataField="ResolvedDate"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Issue" DataField="Issue"></asp:BoundField>  
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` to your GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStatusUpdate" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This was a superb answer. Short and precise.